# Link stylesheets up directories using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, html, css

How do I move up a directory using the `<link>` in HTML for my stylesheets to work while using htaccess?

My directories are as:

```
index.php
.htaccess
css/
    styles.css
php/
   login.php
```

In my htaccess, it contains:

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ php/login.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now, the stylesheets work when I copy the `css` folder to inside my `php`. They work with `href="css/styles.css"`.

I don't want that. I want to move up and out of the `php` directory to the `css` folder in my root directory. But the stylesheets won't show when the `href="../css/styles.css"`.

How do I move up a directory to use my stylesheet in the root css folder with htaccess?

**EDIT:** I have tried using the `<base href="/" />`, but that prevents the stylesheets from loading on both `/login/` and `/login.php`.

### `login.php`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/system.js"></script>
<link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

### `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/Sites/OrderFresh/html/error404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ php/userconnect.php [L,QSA,NC]
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: The base tags prevent the stylesheet from working on both /login/ and /login.php

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute URL?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant `link` and `base` element combinations you have tried to your question. Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Using the absolute error does not work for both for some odd reason. Okay, let me add some of the files.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it. `<link href="/css/styles.css"...`

Comment: Yes, but I need to move up one directory first, for in the php folder has no folder named css.

Comment: The URL-path that Tim suggests already does "move up one directory". It is a root-relative URL-path. If the `css` directory is in the document root, as you stated, then that is all you need (you don't need a `base` element in that case). If, however, you did include a `base` element that references a document in the web root then the path to your js and css files would simply be `"css/styles.css"`. However, if you specified a path of `"../css/styles.css"` with the above `base` element then you would be trying to go above the document root which would fail. This is covered in the dupe question.

Comment: _Aside:_ You shouldn't be using an absolute URL in the `ErrorDocument` directive - this will trigger an external redirect.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the helps and tips. It's a little strange that whenever I add a / before it, it won't recognize it. EDIT: Oh I see now. Yes, I got the base to work. Thanks for the specification.

Comment: WHat error are you getting in the console?

Comment: I can't say that I know. I think I found a fix though now. I'm using Xammp.

Comment: OK, to access the console in Chrome press F12 and it is one of the tabs.  Other browsers may do it differently.  It is one of the best ways to diagnose errors

Answer (score 0):

I get around this problem using site relative linking for CSS and JS files.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/system.js"></script>
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

When the URL starts with a slash, that tells the browser to start at the document root for the site.  Your CSS and JS files will then be correctly linked no matter what directory your page looks like it is in.